# How can I get value from KeyValuePair Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, keyvaluepair

I have to build a Gym timetable with class time, daysofweek and classes, so what I am getting from database is:

Time - Dayofweek - class
08:00 - 1 - Natação
08:00 - 3 - Natação
08:30 - 1 - Jiu-Jitsu
09:00 - 1 - Natação
10:30 - 1 - Jiu-Jitsu
14:00 - 3 - Natação

My Model:

```
 public class Group<K, T>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}

public class Aulas
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idDias { get; set; }
    public DateTime AulaHora { get; set; }
    public string AulaNome { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Context _q = new Context();

       var query = from x in _q.Aulas
                   group x by x.AulaHora into g
                   select new Group<DateTime, Aulas> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };


        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

My View:

```html
@using Grid.Models;
@model List<Group<DateTime, Aulas>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead><tr><th>Horários</th><th>Segunda</th><th>Terça</th><th>Quarta</th><th>Quinta</th><th>Sexta</th><th>Sábado</th></tr></thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {       
            <tr>
                @foreach (var i in item.Values)
                {
                <td>@i.AulaHora.ToString("HH:mm")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 1) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 2) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 3) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 4) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 5) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                <td>@((i.idDias == 6) ? i.AulaNome.ToString() : "")</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have experience with KeyValuePair. If can anyone suggest what I need to do get that I'll really be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each KeyValuePair will contain a .Value property which will give you the value. Please see this MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit after better understanding the issue:

Your problem is two fold.

1. First you are building your query wrong for the type of required output.
2. Second you are looping through your query in your view wrong for it to display as you desire.

If I were you, I would get rid of that `Group` class as that is no longer needed. A `Dictionary` would better suit your needs. I would set up your Model to be a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Aulas>>`.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Aulas>> query = 
    new Dictionary<DateTime, List<Aulas>>();

_c.Aulas.ForEach(
    (a) =>
    {
        if (query.ContainsKey(a.AulaHora))
        {
            query[a.AulaHora].Add(a);
        }
        else
        {
            query.Add(a.AulaHora, new List<Aulas>() { a });
        }
    });

return View(query);
```

Then you will need to loop through them differently to get your desired results.

```
@using Grid.Models;
@model Dictionary<DateTime, List<Aulas>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead><tr><th>Horários</th><th>Segunda</th><th>Terça</th><th>Quarta</th><th>Quinta</th><th>Sexta</th><th>Sábado</th></tr></thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {       
            <tr>
            <td>@(item.Key.ToString("HH:mm"))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 1).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 2).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 3).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 4).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 5).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            <td>@(string.Join(", ", item.Value.Where((wa) => wa.idDias == 6).Select((sa) => sa.AulaNome)))</td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

Just a couple of things. I am creating a dictionary based on the DateTime of the Aulas. If there are matching DateTime keys, then I add the Aulas to the existing entry in the Dictionary. That way, when I loop through them in the View, I am looping by DateTime. Then for each Column (`<td>`) I do a Where clause on the .Value which will be a `List<Aulas>` and a Select query to get the datatype I want. It will pull out all the Aulas that have that specific idDias and join them using the String.Join() method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've already seen this MSDN but as I wrote I haven't experience with keypair and I don't know how to solve this. Could you help me?

Comment: @Rodney Which variable is your KeyValuePair?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you asking.

Comment: @Rodney You're question was about KeyValuePair's and how do you get the value of a KeyValuePair. Well I stated that there is a .Value property that you can use to get the value. You then said you don't know how to solve something. From your code, it is not apparent where there is an issue using a KeyValuePair collection. So using your code above, where is the the KeyValuePair collection and where is your issue? I will update my answer to help if you provide more information.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. In fact, I have two issues there that I need help, first is to build that grid and if the KeyValuePair is the best or possible aproach to get that. Look the pictures for a better understanding...I expect this(http://www.efeitodigital.com.br/right.gif) and I am getting this(http://www.efeitodigital.com.br/wrong.gif).

Comment: Ok. I see the problem. Last question and I can point you in the right direction. Is the _q.Aulas a collection of Aulas?

Comment: Thankyou again for your effort. I am learning a lot with your help, but I am in doubt about _c.Aulas.ForEach(... the correct way is _q.Aulas.ForEach(, isn't it? Either way I getting the message: Error 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Grid.Models.Aulas>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Grid.Models.Aulas>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If its easier for you I put a project copy here(www.efeitodigital.com.br/grid.zip)

Comment: Well. I have pretty much given you everything you need. You never included the code showing the properties of Context so I went with the assumption that _c.Aulas was a simple collection, hopefully a List<Aulas>. The code will work just fine if you are able to turn your _c.Aulas into a List<Aulas>. If you cannot, then just change the _c.Aulas.ForEach(..) to use a typical foreach(var a in _c.Aulas). The same code below that will apply.